# Convert boolean DataFrame to binary number array

Tags: python, pandas

I have a boolean pandas DataFrame, as follow

```
aaa = pd.DataFrame([[False,False,False], [True,True,True]])
```

I want to convert it to a binary number array, for this DataFrame "aaa",
the result is [000,111]

How can I implement this conversion?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
aaa = pd.DataFrame([[False,False,False],
                      [True,True,True]])
aaa=aaa.astype(int)
```

Then `aaa` is

```
    0   1   2
0   0   0   0
1   1   1   1
```

If you want to get the array `['000','111']` you can do:

```
aaa = pd.DataFrame([[False,False,False],
                      [True,True,True]])
aaa=aaa.astype(int).astype(str)
[''.join(i) for i in aaa.values.tolist()]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert after `int` and `str` to `numpy array` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) and then [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
print (aaa.astype(int).astype(str).values.sum(axis=1))
['000' '111']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can multiply by a [bit shifted operator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) to simulate powers of two, sum, then convert to binary

```
aaa.mul(np.arange(3)[::-1] << 1).sum(1).apply(bin)

0      0b0
1    0b110
dtype: object
```

Notice how `np.arange(3)[::-1] << 1` is successive powers of `2`

```
array([4, 2, 0])
```

You can take this further by manipulating with `str` operations

```
aaa.mul(
    np.arange(3)[::-1] << 1
).sum(1).apply(bin).str.replace('0b', '').str.zfill(3)

0    000
1    110
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do one of the following:

```
a.astype(int).astype(str).sum(axis=1).astype(int).astype(str)
```

but this is a bit too much retyping to my taste.

Another possibility is to use apply:

```
a.astype(int).astype(str).apply(lambda x: ''.join(list(x)))
```

But what seems cleanest to me is to obtain the desired number by multiplication, then convert it to binary:

```
a.dot([4, 2, 1]).map(lambda x: bin(x))
```

of course, if you don't want the '0b' on the beginning, you just use

```
a.dot([4, 2, 1]).map(lambda x: bin(x)[2:])
```

Comment: Multiplication is a great idea!